# android define listener in a separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I'm trying to define a listener in a separate thread in my android app, however, the thread exits before that and doesn't wait for the callback functions to be invoked.

Below is the code snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
      public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        obj = <AIDL interface>.Stub.asInterface(service);
      }
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        obj = null;
      }
      Intent intent = new Intent("<service name>");
      context.startService(intent);
      boolean status = context.bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}).start();
```

Now when from the main thread, I start this thread and wait for onServiceConnected() to happen, it waits forever and gets never invoked. I also checked the status of this thread and it says "TERMINATED". Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Where in the run method do you expect it to stop?

Comment: So basically I expect the thread to be alive since it has listener implementation in it. If it terminates, listener will never be invoked.

Comment: When the thread returns from the run() method it is terminated.  This has nothing to do with the lifetime of the objects it may have created.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the bound service.  Do you need a separate thread to do this?   If you are trying to do work in a separate thread, take a look at IntentService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rethink the design of your application.   Some questions that you should know the answer to:

Do you need two-way interaction with the service or can you simply send "requests" to the service?

Are the actions taken in the service quick enough to be done in the UI thread, or do they need to run in a separate thread?

It is quite likely that you can make the service an IntentService and interact with it by sending requests using StartService(Intent) without needing to bind to the service at all, but without answers to the above questions it is hard to tell.

Edit:

In the run method set m_stopping (a new member variable) to false before binding to the service.

After issuing the bind request:

```
while(!m_stopping)
{
   do_some useful work here (otherwise, why have a thread?)
   This may include calling unbindService() when you are done.
}
```

And in the implementation of ServiceConnection::onServiceDisconnected(component) method set m_stopping to false.

Comment: I should have been more clear in describing the problem above. What I'm trying to achieve is the following: The startService() and bindService() calls are asynchronous by nature and I'm trying to make that synchronous by putting the connection listener, bindService()/startService() in different threads so I can use wait/notify mechanism to sync. But the thread in which I define the connection object listener (onServiceConnected()) terminates immediately (obviously that will happen) and I'm trying to figure out how I can keep that alive. Hope that explains what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The code snippet above doesn't have wait/notify since at this point of time, I'm trying to figure out if I can implement onServiceConnected() in a thread as above and keep it running to get callbacks.

Comment: I'm not able to understand your edited answer. Is that how I can keep the thread containing ServiceConnection listener implementation alive? Is that what you meant?

Comment: That will keep the thread alive until the service is unbound, yes.   You need to be sure that you understand that threads do not "contain" objects.  The ServiceConnection created by the thread will continue to exist as long as there is a reference to it, even if the thread that creates terminates by returning from the run method.

Comment: Yep, I understand that and tried doing the similar thing. However, onServiceConnected() still didn't get invoked. That is probably due to main thread being blocked (since I put it on wait until onServiceConnected() is called) and this documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) says that the main thread invokes onServiceConnected(). Since that's blocked, it can never invoke onServiceConnected() and hence it formed a deadlock. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  That's why onServiceConnected() is a callback, binding to a service may take too long to run it on the UI thread -- particularly if the service happens to be in another Application and process. In general, on Android, waiting for something to happen is not a good idea (this is a very high level generalization, not a hard-and-fast rule.)  Initiate things (like service binding) then return.  Respond to events (like the connection being established) when they happen.  That's why I keep wondering if/why you need a thread in the first place.